# How to insert and update records from dummy table to main table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to insert and update records from dummy table to main table with same attributes on two conditions are same.
Example If Id and Date part are same in both table then records should be updated
If id is not same in dummy table then record should be inserted
If id is same but date is not same in dummy then also records should be inserted

Comment: You should update your post with information not cram a bunch of stuff into comments.

Comment: please add details to the question and not the comments and decide if you're using sql-server or mysql... they aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use trigger. for example set trigger for insert to table-

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON empsalarydummy
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO empsalary VALUES (NEW.ID, NEW.NAME, NEW.SALARYDATE, NEW.SALARY, NEW.RANK);
  END;
|
```

i have set it for insert. we can also set it for update example-

```
DELIMITER ///

CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER UPDATE ON empsalarydummy
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN            
            UPDATE empsalary SET SALARY=NEW.SALARY WHERE SALARY=OLD.SALARY;
    END;
///
```